# 400 No Host matches server name 127.0.0.1

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, target

Without changing something my webapplication refuses to load today.
I am using JBoss 4.0 and am deploying a web application using Inteli J IDE.

Initially I had the application at http://localhost:8080/app

Yesterday everything was working fine. 
Today I am trying to run the application and am recieving a blank page.
Below is a screenshot from the debugger:

[image]

### Update

I noticed that when I deploy 1 out of the 2 war's, I can access some addresses.
I am starting to suspect there is a problem with a `Servlet context listener` for one of the two war's.

### Update 2

I see in the logs the following message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/cache/aop/PojoCacheMBean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the deployed `war`. It seems if the deployment fails, this error is thrown for that `context`.

The solution in the specific case was to make a completely new/fresh and clean `InteliJ` project, and redo everything from the start with a fresh checkout.